# Handle pointers to components created inside a loop

Tags: delphi, pointers

First of all: sorry for my english, hope to be able to explain what I need.
Also consider I'm new to Delphi. Thanks in advance to everyone who'll try to help me.

I have this situation:

a global var

```
atd : array of ^TLabel
```

Some procedures that ADD dynamically labels to a scrollbox

Below you'll find one of them

```
procedure LabelINIT();
var L : Tlabel;
begin

....

while not DATASET.EOF do
  begin
    L := TLabel.Create(Self);
    L.Parent := ScrollBox3;
    L.Height := 13;
    L.Width := 30;
    L.Left := atd[DATASET.FIELDS[0].ASINTEGER].Left;
    L.Top := atd[DATASET.FIELDS[0].ASINTEGER].Top + 3
    ...
    atd[DATASET.FIELDS[0].ASINTEGER] := @L;
    DATASET.NEXT;
  end; 

.....

end;
```

ATD should store the address of the last inserted label... but in reality it stores the address of L variable, so on every new loop ATD points to the new L created at the beggining of the while. Worst of all when out of the procedure I can't use values in ATD 'cause they reference to invalid addresses (L is a local var).

I'd like to know if there's a way to point directly to the created label instead of pointing to a variable that's a copy of it.

In other words what I'd like to do is: create a LABEL - FIND ITS OWN ADDRESS - POINT to IT

What I've done is: create a LABEL, set a VARIABLE = LABEL, POINT TO THE VAR

Comment: Remove `^` and `@` chars from your code and you should be fine ;-)

Comment: Thanks, this could be a solution, but I'll have an array of TLabels, that's a lot bigger than an array of pointers, also considering that atd could store up to 200 values and I have other 3 arrays of the same type for other 3 scrollboxes...

Comment: @Bux No. `array of TLabel` is an array of pointers.

Comment: OK. David has explained me something that I didn't know. Your solution is OK! Thanks

Comment: @Bux Am I right in thinking that you arrive at Delphi with knowledge of C++?

Comment: @David. yes you are really right ;)

Comment: In Delphi an instance of a type declared with `class` cannot be a value. One consequence is that you cannot place instances on the stack. You don't get object slicing in Delphi which is nice. You refer to instance in Delphi the same way you do in C# or Java. When you right `x: TObject` in Delphi it's the same as `TObject* x` in C++. When you write `x.Foo` in Delphi that would be `x->Foo()` in C++.

Comment: Actually in Turbo Pascal with Objects those objects were like C++ ones in this intent.  You had to use like `type ttt = object(parent) ... end; var ooo: ^ttt;  New(ooo, ConstructorMethodName(....)) ; ooo^.MethodName(...); Dispose( ooo,  DestructorMethodName) ;` However it fallen out of fashion and the only large Delphi project that uses it known to me is performance-oriented mORMot library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's look at the code you have:

```
procedure LabelINIT;
var 
  L: TLabel;
begin
  ....
  atd[DATASET.FIELDS[0].ASINTEGER] := @L;
  ....
end;
```

Now, `L` is a local variable. And so `@L` is the address of that local variable. When `LabelINIT` returns, that address is no longer valid because the variables life has ended.

The information that you are missing is that a variable of type `TLabel` is in fact a pointer already. That variable is a pointer to the object instance. Any variable in Delphi of a type that inherits from `TObject` is a pointer to the object instance.

So, the solution is simple. Change the global variable as so:

```
atd: array of TLabel;
```

This is an array of pointers to label instances.

Change the assignment to `atd` to be like so:

```
atd[DATASET.FIELDS[0].ASINTEGER] := L;
```

---

Although I've referred to these variables as being pointers, they are more commonly referred to as references in Delphi-speak. In due course I think you'll come round to that terminology, but I used pointer in this answer to make it explicitly clear what these things are.

From the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Classes_and_Objects#Class_Types):

> A variable of a class type is actually a pointer that references an object. Hence more than one variable can refer to the same object. Like other pointers, class-type variables can hold the value `nil`. But you don't have to explicitly dereference a class-type variable to access the object it points to. For example, `SomeObject.Size := 100` assigns the value `100` to the `Size` property of the object referenced by `SomeObject`; you would not write this as `SomeObject^.Size := 100`.